Fantasy book involving a thief stealing a rainbow horn artifact
A master thief that gets roped in by the nation's king into exploring an elven crypt for some magical rainbow horn artifact.
I remember there being a heist in the first chapter, with something about a special kind of flooring that reverberates sound and a guard dog.

This might be Shadow Prowler (2010) by
Alexey Pehov.  (Originally released in Russian in 2002 as Крадущийся в тени.)

The titular thief needs to steal the Rainbow Horn to defeat the Nameless One.
Quoting the book description from Goodreads:

After centuries of calm, the Nameless One is stirring. An army is giants, ogres and other creatures joining forces from across the Desolate Lands, united for the first time in history under one black banner. By the spring, or perhaps sooner, the Nameless One and his forces will be at the walls of the great city of Avendoom. Unless Shadow Harold, master thief, can find some way to stop them. Epic fantasy at its best, Shadow Prowler is the first in a trilogy that follows professional thief Shadow Harold on his quest for a magic Horn that will restore peace to the kingdom of Siala. Accompanied by an elfin princess, ten Wild Hearts - the most experienced and dangerous royal fighters - and the King's court jester (who may be more than he seems ...or less), Harold must outwit angry demons, escape the clutches of a band of hired murderers, survive ten bloody skirmishes ...and reach the burial grounds before dark. Can he escape a fate worse than death?

A review mentions the Rainbow Horn:

Shadow Harold is a professional thief. His latest Commission (thieving job) has gotten him in a bit of trouble. He hasn’t exactly gotten caught, just noticed by the wrong people. The kingdom of Siala is overrun with a mysterious yellow fog and demons that hunt in the shadows. Everyone thinks the Namesless One is to blame--a figure of darkness both evil and powerful who sends his minions forth to carry out terrible deeds. The Order of Magicians bring Harold forward with a proposition: journey to Hrad Spein and the Palace of Bones to retrieve the Rainbow Horn or be sent to the Gray Stones for his perpetual thieving crimes. The Rainbow Horn is a magical instrument sure to break the bond that ties the Nameless One to this world; the Gray Stones is the worst prison imaginable. Harold doesn’t have to think very hard about his decision and it isn’t long before he’s off to the Forbidden Territory in search of a map that will help him navigate Hrad Spein.

